# Exporting select from two MySQL tables to one JSON file

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

How can I run a query against a database with two tables `client` and `appointment` to out put JSON like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "app1": null,
    "app2": null,
    "app3":[
            "cname": "John",
            "clastname": "Doe",
            "cemail": "john@doe.com",
            "cphone": "604",
    ],
    "app4":[
            "cname": "Mark",
            "clastname": "Martini",
            "cemail": "mark@martini.com",
            "cphone": "778",
    ]
}
```

As you can see I need to get `null` when the `app`x  fields are null and load with `client` table data where the `appx = cilentid`

Here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE Client (
id INT(6),
cname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
clastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
cemail VARCHAR(50),
cphone VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO Client 
    (`id`, `cname`, `clastname`, `cemail`, `cphone`) 
VALUES 
   (25, 'John', 'Doe', 'john@doe.com', '604'),
   (60 ,'Mark', 'Martini', 'mark@martini.com', '778')
 ;
 
 
 CREATE TABLE appointments (
id INT(6),
app1 INT(6)  DEFAULT NULL,
app2 INT(6)  DEFAULT NULL,
app3 INT(6) DEFAULT NULL,
app4 INT(6) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO appointments 
    (`id`, `app1`, `app2`, `app3`, `app4`) 
VALUES 
   (1,null,null,null,60),
   (2,25,null,null,null)
 ;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a working MySQL query that will give you the results that you need ? Is there a reason that your appointment table is designed the way it is ?

Comment: Thanks for reply but I need to design at that way. I mean the `appointment` the app1 is in fact `9-10` and app2 is `10-11` and so on. I couldn't find a better way to deal with this.

Comment: What if you create an appointment type table `(appointment_id, start_time, end_time)`, change the current appointment table to an associative table `(appointment_id, client_id)`. That way you can have any no. of appointments rather than the current limit of 4. With the current structure, if you need to add another appointment type, you'll need to add another column to the appointment table which is not recommended. It's easier to add rows to a table then add columns to it.

Comment: I need to get 10 appointment in a day so I thought it is better to keep the appointments in one table

Comment: You can still do that with the schema that I suggested. If you change no. of appointments from 10 to 15 then you'd to add that many more columns most of which would be NULL anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You can always `SELECT` those appointments, loop through the results and place them into arrays, loop those arrays and fetch whatever you need from the next table.

```
$counter = 0;
$my_array=[];
$query = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM appoints');
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $my_array[$counter][$key] = ((int) $value > 0 ? (mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id =' . (int) $usr))) : 'null');
    }
    $counter++;
}
var_export(json_encode($my_array));
```

In the end you can `json_encode` the whole array.

I'd rather redesign the whole thing but this will give a you a good idea on how to deal with this particular problem.